# Stacked to tuple list like they want in output

Tags: python, list, tuples

Enumerate has to split data by ";".
Clean has to remove strings that contains "//" and "..".
complete_missing_values has to add "txt" if string ends ".".
accumulate has to group strings like it's shown in output (it can be on one row, i wrote it one under other to see it correctly)
accumulate should be written in one row. Don't know how to do it. Please help.

```
def data_preprocessing_tree(data):
    enumerate = data.split(";")

    clean = list(filter(lambda k: not '//'  in k and not '..' in k, enumerate))

    complete_missing_values = list(map(lambda x: x+"txt" if (x[-1] == '.')  else x,clean))

    print(complete_missing_values)
    accumulate =

Blockquote

data="/User/someuser/file.py;/tmp/download/file.zip;/tmp/download/file2.zip;/;/usr/local/bin;/User/someuser/file..py;/tmp/file.;/usr//some"
data_preprocessing_tree(data)
#Output:
#[('/tmp/download', ('file.zip', 'file2.zip')),
# ('/tmp', ('file.txt',)),
# ('/User/someuser', ('file.py',)),
# ('/', ()),
# ('/usr/local/bin', ())
#]
```

my output before accumulate:['/User/someuser/file.py', '/tmp/download/file.zip', '/tmp/download/file2.zip', '/', '/usr/local/bin', '/tmp/file.txt']

Comment: `enumerate` is the name of a python built-in function.  It is very bad practice to assign something different to that name - but note that `Enumerate` is not the same.    Is this homework?

Comment: yes. enumerate it's just a variable in that case. i did 3/4 parts of assignement. that means i coded enumerate, clean and complete_missing_values

Comment: So i need to use complete_missing_values result, to write accumulate

Comment: Variable names and function names are not differentiated in python, a function is an object just like anything else.

Comment: But i still don't know how to realize accumulate